# We said the data is normally distributed, based on the raw data or residual?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a confusing regarding the assumption test for the data, in some theory were said that there are three assumption of data as we called as "good" data:

1. Independent
2. Normally distributed
3. Homogeneity

my question are:
Referring to point (2) and (3),

1. We said the data is normally distributed, based on the raw data or residual?
   I have a case when i was conducting the ANOVA analysis, the assumption for ANOVA is normal and homogeneity, what i did until now is to check this through the residual (after i got the model ANOVA), is it true?
2. if those assumption come from raw data not residual, how I can check the homogeneity? bartlett is using residual that I know to check the homogeneity..

thanks..for your input.!